# Format table using python so that the rows from one column are moved to a single comma separated row, and grouped by ID

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a table that looks like the table below, there is an ID column and a barcode column. Each ID may have multiple barcodes and barcodes may be shared between the IDs.

[image]

I want the output to look like the second table where all the barcodes associated with an ID are in a single row and separated by a comma. I am not sure how this can be done in excel. Does anyone know if this is possible? I would also be open to doing this in python.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = df.groupby("ID").agg(lambda x: ",".join(map(str, x))).reset_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
             ID                   Barcode
0  TCHAN-000001            1234,1235,1236
1  TCHAN-000002  1234,1235,1236,1237,1238
```